# Java: How do you print an array? "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, arrays

```
System.out.println(someArray);
```

Just gives me a single address, that I assume is the address where the values are stored.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(someArray));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(someArray));
```

Both of these cannot compile and say 'cannot find symbol', with the symbol being: 'variable Arrays'.

How can I see which values are in this array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 'cannot find symbol', with the symbol being: 'variable Arrays'

You are missing `import java.util.Arrays` import statement on top of the class.

Comment: Oh, yea of course, for some reason assumed I wouldn't have to do that.

Thanks everyone who answered

Comment: @Nate: I hope now both statements returning what you are expecting. Enjoy coding.

Answer (score 3):

How about a loop?:

```
for (T item : someArray)
    System.out.println(item);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Then you'll be able to do:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(someArray));
```

or

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(someArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try to import `java.util.Arrays`.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to import `java.util.Arrays`.

Add the import statement like this:

```
your.some.package;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class SomeClass {
   public void someMethod() {
      System.out.println(Arrays.asList(someArray));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Just gives me a single address, that I assume is the address where the
>   values are stored.

Not really where the values are stored, but rather the beginning of the addressed space for your array.

I don't really use java.util.Arrays so I don't know that library.  You can always print out an array by iterating through it and printing out each item's contents as you wish--so as long as each part you want to print has a toString() method written for it.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, java.util.Arrays also contains [deepToString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score -1):

TRY THIS:
`enter code here`

```
for(int i=0;i<=size_of_ur_array;i++)
{
  System.out.println(""+someArray[i]);
}
```

here above size_of_ur array will be the number that you used to give it a maximum upper limit.
since array are stored using indexes so you need to access them in indexed way i.e first element will be a[0],second a[1] and so on upto your upper limit.